# Basic setup of an Aerohive AP245X via CLI

Tags: configuration, command-line-interface, wifi

I recently acquired an Aerohive AP secondhand without a GUI.  I reset it by pressing the button for however long.  Now I want to set it up as a normal WiFi AP w/o any fancy Hive stuff.  Just one SSID with the most bandwidth and range.

I couldn't find a CLI manual for my specific one (AP245X rev. A).  I can SSH into it. Any ideas on what commands to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** read this instead: https://gist.github.com/samdoran/6bb5a37c31a738450c04150046c1c039

I figured it out (with a lot of help from the `?` key).  This is what I did:

```bash
#disables some sort of management thing
no capwap client enable

#creates a password
security-object MyWifiNetwork

#sets the password and encryption method
security-object MyWifiNetwork security protocol-suite wpa2-aes-psk ascii-key superawesomepassword

#creates a network name
ssid MyWifiNetwork

#assigns the password to the network name
ssid MyWifiNetwork security-object MyWifiNetwork

#I forget what this does (these comments are an edit)
security-object MyWifiNetwork default-user-profile-attr 0

#sets the 2.4GHz radio to use the network name
interface wifi0 ssid MyWifiNetwork

#sets the 5GHz radio to use the network name
interface wifi1 ssid MyWifiNetwork

#the AP asks clients to use 5GHz if possible
radio profile MyWifiNetwork band-steering enable

#the AP asks clients to use 5GHz if fewer than 80% of clients are on 5GHz
radio profile MyWifiNetwork band-steering balance-band threshold 80

#by default the Aerohives like to have a backhaul on 5GHz band. This disables that
interface wifi1 mode access

#this feels pretty self-explanatory
save config

#print to console the list of interfaces and what are assigned to do
show interface
```

The Aerohives all use the same default hive id, so if you set up more than one on the same ethernet network, they might find each other and cooperate, but I'm not sure. Good luck!